# Can't find the reason for NullPointerException; Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, forceclose

I have been getting a NullPointerExcpetion in the LogCat stack, and I can't seem to figure out why. I just hope some outside eyes will help me find the issue.

Here is the stack from LogCat:

```
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524): java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at vt.nhw.android.easyringertoggle.ScheduleDbAdapter.createSchedule(ScheduleDbAdapter.java:77)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at vt.nhw.android.easyringertoggle.ScheduleEditActivity.saveState(ScheduleEditActivity.java:195)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at vt.nhw.android.easyringertoggle.ScheduleEditActivity.access$3(ScheduleEditActivity.java:189)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at vt.nhw.android.easyringertoggle.ScheduleEditActivity$5.onClick(ScheduleEditActivity.java:135)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at  android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    10-28 02:04:55.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(524):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The stack seems to be pointing to the saveState() method and the createSchedule() method. The relevant lines have been double asterisked.

saveState():

```
private void saveState() {
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
    String scheduleDateTime = dateTimeFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());

    if (mRowId == null) {
        **long id = mDbHelper.createSchedule(title, scheduleDateTime);**
        if(id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateSchedule(mRowId, title, scheduleDateTime);
    }
}
```

createSchedule():

```
public long createSchedule(String title, String scheduleDateTime) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, scheduleDateTime);
    **return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);**
}
```

Please let me know if I need to post any other code. Thank you for any help that you can give me.

Regards,
Jason

Comment: If you have a null pointer in `createSchedule()`, then it's either `initialValue` or `mDb`. I would guess the latter.

Answer (score 1):

`mDb` seems to be NULL because this is the only variable that is global.